# How to get the head field of ps command?

Tags: command-line, ps

```
ps -el |grep  systemd
4 S     0     1     0  0  80   0 -  7233 -      ?        00:00:00 systemd
```

How to get the following output format?

```
ps -el |grep  systemd
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S     0     1     0  0  80   0 -  7233 -      ?        00:00:00 systemd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ps` can search for command names:

```
$ ps -lC systemd
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S     0     1     0  1  80   0 - 33838 ep_pol ?        00:00:01 systemd
4 S  1000   733     1  0  80   0 - 15347 ep_pol ?        00:00:00 systemd
```

Or using `pgrep` to search instead:

```
$ ps -l -p $(pgrep -d, systemd)
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
4 S     0     1     0  0  80   0 - 33838 ep_pol ?        00:00:01 systemd
4 S     0   242     1  0  80   0 - 60300 ep_pol ?        00:00:00 systemd-journal
4 S     0   275     1  0  80   0 - 11267 ep_pol ?        00:00:00 systemd-udevd
4 S     0   546     1  0  80   0 - 11228 ep_pol ?        00:00:00 systemd-logind
4 S  1000   733     1  0  80   0 - 15347 ep_pol ?        00:00:00 systemd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `-e` flag to grep, to ask it to find extra pattern in the first row, like this:

`ps -el | grep -e systemd -e "TIME CMD"`